# How to draw a hierarchical structure with edges?

Tags: diagrams, technical-drawing

I would like to show such a structure in my LaTeX document. How can this be done?

[image]

Comment: Have a look to [Work breakdown structures](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/work-breakdown-structure/): it's a good starting point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`dirtree`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dirtree) package is built for producing diagrams like this.  Below I give its default style and then show how to adjust the parameters to get something closer to your hand drawing.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dirtree}

\begin{document}

\dirtree{%
.1 HTML.
.2 Head.
.3 Title.
.3 Meta.
.2 Body.
.3 SVG.
.4 Image.
}

\renewcommand{\DTstyle}{\textrm\expandafter\raisebox{-0.7ex}}
\DTsetlength{1em}{1em}{0.2em}{0.4pt}{0.4pt}
\setlength{\DTbaselineskip}{2\baselineskip}

\dirtree{%
.1 HTML.
.2 Head.
.3 Title.
.3 Meta.
.2 Body.
.3 SVG.
.4 Image.
}

\end{document}
```

The parameter changes that are made in the second example are as follows:

1. The style of the nodes is changed so that (a) we use a standard text font and (b) the node is shifted down relative to the horizontal lines
2. The standard lengths of `dirtree` are adjusted, so that (a) the dots at the cross are the same wdith `0.4pt` as the lines, this is the last two parameters and (b) the vertical lines are moved further under the nodes, the first parameter `1em`.  The second and third parameters have their standard value
3. The internal baseline skip of `dirtree` is made larger, moving the lines apart and moving the tops of the vertial lines down, so they don't cover the shifted text.

Comment: AWESOME! The code looks very nice and clean. Thank you very much. Is there the possibility of displaying three trees in a row next to each other?

Comment: No problem, just put each `\dirtree` in a minipage of width say `0.3\linewdith` and collect them together in a `center` environment.