# How to make Directory List in LaTeX?

Tags: lists, trees, folders

I am writing an article using LaTeX. It is a research report about developing mathematics ebook using LaTeX. It contains directory list consists of folders and files, like this:

```
    - [folder_icon][folder_name]
      + [file_icon][file_name.extension]
      - [folder_icon][folder_name]
        [file_icon][file_name.extension]
```

For example:

```
    - [icon][MatheBook]
      + [icon][math_ebook.tex]
      - [icon][Pictures]
        [icon][math.png]
```

How to do that? I am using MikTeX and TeXnicCenter.

Comment: Duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23647/drawing-a-directory-listing-a-la-the-tree-command-in-tikz

Comment: Do you have special requirements concerning the layout of the list?  If not, I agree with @zunbeltz that this is a duplicate.  Look also at http://ctan.org/pkg/dirtree

Comment: I've read your references, but these examples without including icon.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Making a (simple) directory tree](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5073/5764)

Comment: @Werner a more explanatory duplicate: [How to draw a hierarchical structure with edges?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99578)

Answer (score 11):

Since you seem to think that the `dirtree` solutions won't work, here's an example which I think will show you that they can.

You simply need to create a macro to generate the icon/name pair.  Since I don't know how you are implementing your icons, I've made a mock-up here.  You'd need to modify it to match the way your icons are actually generated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{dirtree}
% The following is a dummy icon command
\newcommand\myicon[1]{{\color{#1}\rule{2ex}{2ex}}}
% If you have actual icon images, use \includegraphics to include them
% If you are generating them, put in the appropriate code for them here
% now we make a command for a folder/file which inserts the icon and its label
% adjust this as needed. If you only have 2 icons, then you could create
% a \myfile and \myfolder command with the icon fixed.
\newcommand{\myfolder}[2]{\myicon{#1}\ {#2}}

\begin{document}

\dirtree{%
.1 \myfolder{red}{Mathbook}.
.2 \myfolder{blue}{Pictures}.
.3 \myfolder{green}{math.png}.
.3 \myfolder{green}{math2.png}.
.2 \myfolder{blue}{Exercises}.
.4 \myfolder{brown}{Something}.
}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]