# Trees in latex : Depth of 4 nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-trees, trees

I am following the current tutorial (MWE) : [link](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/filesystem-tree/)

However, I am facing difficulties to perform a tree of 4 nodes. Items are superposed, and even if I add a    `child [missing] {}`   it doesn't solve the issue.

On below an example of code which is not displayed correctly :

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thick,anchor=west]
\tikzstyle{selected}=[draw=red,fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{optional}=[dashed,fill=gray!50]
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.7) and
  two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.4)},
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}]
\node {texmf}
    child { node {doc}}     
    child { node {fonts}}
    child { node {source}}
    child { node [selected] {tex}
      child { node {generic}}
      child { 
         node [optional] {latex}
         child { node {latex21} }
         child { node {latex22} }
         child { node {latex23} }
      }
      child [missing] {}              
      child [missing] {}              
      child [missing] {}              
      child { 
         node {plain}
         child { node {plain21} }
         child { node {plain22} }
         child { node {plain23} }
         }
      child [missing] {}              
      child [missing] {}              
      child [missing] {}              
    }
    child [missing] {}              
    child [missing] {}              
    child [missing] {}              
    child [missing] {}              
    child [missing] {}              
    child [missing] {}              
    child { node {texdoc}};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Issue of display, textdoc should be on below]

Actually, I do not understand where and when to use `child [missing] {}`. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The following question might be useful: (possibly a duplicate) [Drawing a directory listing a la the tree command in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23647).  Also, there is the `dirtree` package, which doesn't use `tikz`: [How to draw a hierarchical structure with edges?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99578). For an alternative tree input syntax, (much easier) you can also use `tikz-qtree`.  See [Horizontal hierarchy tree in tikz-qtree: bad layout for longer node-names](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41490) for an example like yours.

Comment: @AlanMunn : Yes I've already seen this post. However I do like having the boxes, and I rather like this style. Thanks

Comment: @Header12 Politely asking you to respect the policy on this site is neither ironic, nor unwarranted criticism. This was no personal attack, just a constructive suggestion with no irony present. If you are willing to use this site, you might as well try to follow its rules. I removed the comments since you were kind enough to improve on your question. I also wish you good luck and refer you to my provided answer.

Comment: @Header12 Just to explain why we like actual code rather than links: links die over time, so all Stack Exchange sites discourage links that are not within the Stack Exchange domain, especially as they pertain to the main content of a question or answer.

Comment: You both got points. I really thought that @MHaaZ was trolling me. I now understand. Thank you for the help, and sorry for my having react in that way.

Comment: @Header12 Thanks to you for being big enough to apologize. No hard feelings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:**

You should add 3 more `child[missing]` if you want the `texdoc` node to be "on its own" horizontally.

**Long answer:**

`Tikz` actually tries to grow balanced trees, so for drawing a directory like this, a little bit of "magic" is necessary: the `missing` nodes. For further insight into how `missing` nodes work, you could take a look into the the pgf/TikZ manual.
Basically TikZ draws trees without consideration of node sizes, and thus with this code it is necessary to "skip" some nodes (mark them as `missing`) to get the correct placement.
For two nodes *a* and *b* at level 2, you should insert as many `missing` nodes inbetween as there are descendants of *a* (children and grandchildren and so on...). This is to make the tree "skip" as many nodes as necessary to put *b* in its right place. In your case, there are 6 leaf nodes (level 4) and 3 middle nodes (level 3), so you need to "skip" 9 nodes. The code below:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thick,anchor=west]
\tikzstyle{selected}=[draw=red,fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{optional}=[dashed,fill=gray!50]
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.7) and
  two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.4)},
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}]
\node {texmf}
    child { node {doc}}     
    child { node {fonts}}
    child { node {source}}
    child { node [selected] {tex}
      child { node {generic}}
      child { 
         node [optional] {latex}
         child { node {latex21} }
         child { node {latex22} }
         child { node {latex23} }
      }
      child [missing] {}              
      child [missing] {}              
      child [missing] {}              
      child { 
         node {plain}
         child { node {plain21} }
         child { node {plain22} }
         child { node {plain23} }
         }
      child [missing] {}              
      child [missing] {}              
      child [missing] {}              
    }
    child [missing] {}              
    child [missing] {}              
    child [missing] {}              
    child [missing] {}              
    child [missing] {}              
    child [missing] {}
    child [missing] {}              
    child [missing] {}              
    child [missing] {}                            
    child { node {texdoc}};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

yields the following image, which hopefully is what you wanted:

[image: The OP's tree with the correct spacing for nodes]

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. Working great so far, I now understand. Regards.