# Print “Box drawing characters” from shell in lstlisting

Tags: xetex, unicode, terminal-output

I have some output from the `tree` command, which looks something like this:

```
.
├── Maildir/
└── scripts/
    ├── backup.sh*
    └── OLD/
        ├── backup_cleanup.sh.old
        └── backup.sh.old*
```

However, when I copy this into my XeLaTeX document, it ends up similar to this in it's final form:

```
.
??? Maildir/
??? scripts/
    ??? backup.sh*
    ??? OLD/
        ??? backup_cleanup.sh.old
        ??? backup.sh.old*
```

Having done some searching, I've tried using the `verbatim`, `Verbatim`, and `VerbatimOut` environments, however none have successfully presented it.  I have also tried using the `lstlisting` which is what I would prefer to use as I'm using it elsewhere in the document, though that hasn't made any difference.  My `lstlisting` environment is set up like this:

```
\lstset{
    frame=shadowbox,
    rulesepcolor=\color{blue},
    language=bash,
    basicstyle=\fontspec{PT Mono},
    %extendedchars=true,
    %literate={á}{{\'a}}1 {ã}{{\~a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1,
}
```

Those last two lines I found [here](http://www.faqoverflow.com/tex/24528.html), and had hoped that I could find the equivalent escape codes for all the extra symbols, however after a couple of hours of searching, I have failed.

How can I get this structure into my document as text (I'd prefer not to import is as an image)?

Many thanks

EDIT 04/11/14: It turns out that in its default installation, TeXShop saves files in Wester (Mac OS Roman), and when I saved and reopened the file, *it* had replaced the 'special' files with ???.  So changing it all to UTF-16, I can now save and reopen to see the 'special' characters, but when I typeset my document it just shows whitespace...

Comment: How about using [`dirtree`](http://ctan.org/pkg/dirtree) to draw the structured diagram? See [How to draw a hierarchical structure with edges?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99578/5764)

Comment: That looks quite promising.  I think I'd need to parse the output of my `tree` command somewhat to input the numbers as I've got considerably more items than I showed in my example above.  But should give me something to work with, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is whether the font used for typesetting has the needed characters in it.

The example below works on a linux system. Using Microsoft's truetype fonts also works using `\setmonofont{Courier New}`, instead.

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{fontspec}

\setmonofont{FreeMono}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{verbatim}
 .
├── Maildir/
└── scripts/
    ├── backup.sh*
    └── OLD/
        ├── backup_cleanup.sh.old
        └── backup.sh.old*

 \end{verbatim}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: I've changed the font to Courier New, but when I typeset it I get whitespace (see updated question)

Comment: Is this the case using my example above as well, or only your own file.

Comment: It works with your example.  Meaning something is broken with either my encoding, or the contents.  Combing time!

Comment: If that's the case, then perhaps you'd consider marking my response as a correct answer.

Comment: I use the `\setmonofont{Courier New}`, and build this example under Xelatex, and it get the correct result.