# Output from tree command in a listing

Tags: beamer, listings, output

I'm trying to put the output of the tree command in a lstlisting using the following code

```
   \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,compress,svgnames]{beamer}
    \begin{document}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \begin[fragile]{frame}
        \begin{lstlisting}
        5053
        ├── 20141018105053_100_samples.bin
        ├── 20141018105053_101_samples.bin
        ├── 20141018105053_102_samples.bin
        ├── 20141018105053_105_samples.bin
        └── out
            ├── 20141018105053_100_samples.bin.pps
            ├── 20141018105053_101_samples.bin.pps
            ├── 20141018105053_102_samples.bin.pps
            ├── 20141018105053_105_samples.bin.pps
            └── TOA_train.npy
        \end{lstlisting}
    \end{frame}     
    \end{document}
```

but I'm getting this output
[image]
How can I make the lines appear on the output document?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The output of `tree` on your machine uses special UTF-8 characters `├`, `─`, `└` to draw the lines. On the one hand, these characters are not available in the standard LaTeX fonts. On the other hand, `listings` itself is not capable to typeset multibyte characters.

To include the output "as is" in you LaTeX document, a simple solution would be to use listings `literate` option to transparently transform these characters into something that `listings` can typeset:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
  \lstdefinestyle{ascii-tree}{
    literate={├}{|}1 {─}{--}1 {└}{+}1 
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{lstlisting}[style=ascii-tree]
5053
├── 20141018105053_100_samples.bin
├── 20141018105053_101_samples.bin
├── 20141018105053_102_samples.bin
├── 20141018105053_105_samples.bin
└── out
    ├── 20141018105053_100_samples.bin.pps
    ├── 20141018105053_101_samples.bin.pps
    ├── 20141018105053_102_samples.bin.pps
    ├── 20141018105053_105_samples.bin.pps
    └── TOA_train.npy
\end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}     
\end{document}
```

[image]

This basically mimics the `tree` output on a terminal that does not feature UTF-8. However, you could substitute with whatever you want (even macros), so the output could be improved even further. In the following, I replace them by some (plain) line drawing commands:

```
  \lstdefinestyle{tree}{
    literate=
    {├}{{\smash{\raisebox{-1ex}{\rule{1pt}{\baselineskip}}}\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{1ex}{1pt}}}}1 
    {─}{{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{1.5ex}{1pt}}}}1 
    {└}{{\smash{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{1pt}{\dimexpr\baselineskip-1.5ex}}}\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{1ex}{1pt}}}}1 
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{lstlisting}[style=tree]
5053
├── 20141018105053_100_samples.bin
├── 20141018105053_101_samples.bin
├── 20141018105053_102_samples.bin
├── 20141018105053_105_samples.bin
└── out
    ├── 20141018105053_100_samples.bin.pps
    ├── 20141018105053_101_samples.bin.pps
    ├── 20141018105053_102_samples.bin.pps
    ├── 20141018105053_105_samples.bin.pps
    └── TOA_train.npy
\end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: For some reason, I can't get it to work with LuaLaTeX

Comment: LuaLaTex directly supports UTF8, so it might be enough to just include the `tree` output directly into a `verbatim` environment.

Comment: Unfortunately no, even in a `verbatim` environment I have about the same output as OP in its original question. I might end up posting a new question for this unfortunately.

Comment: It does not work under Xelatex, this is the same issue as @AntoineBolvy said. I'm not  sure why.

Comment: BTW: I just tried the pdflatex command, it works fine.

Comment: OK, problem solved, under xelatex, I have to set the font, such as `\setmonofont{Courier New}`, and I can use xelatex to print the tree structure without the `\lstdefinestyle` hacks, see some reference answers here: [Print “Box drawing characters” from shell in lstlisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208941/print-box-drawing-characters-from-shell-in-lstlisting)

Comment: Mmmh, I get a bunch of  `Package utf8x Error: MalformedUTF-8sequence` when trying to include a `tree` file with `\lstinputlisting`

Answer (score 9):

May be you should use `dirtree` package:

```
   \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,compress,svgnames]{beamer}
   \usepackage{dirtree}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \dirtree{%
        .1 5053 .
        .2 20141018105053\_100\_samples.bin.
        .2 20141018105053\_101\_samples.bin.
        .2 20141018105053\_102\_samples.bin.
        .2 20141018105053\_105\_samples.bin.
        .2 out .
            .3 20141018105053\_100\_samples.bin.pps.
            .3 20141018105053\_101\_samples.bin.pps.
            .3 20141018105053\_102\_samples.bin.pps.
            .3 20141018105053\_105\_samples.bin.pps.
            .3 TOA\_train.npy.
        }
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

The package does not seem to be included in mainstream Latex distribution but it can be downloaded from [CTAN here](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/dirtree).
[image]

Comment: Just tried in article class, works fine (but requires manual installation in my case). And a lot easier than the accepted answer! ;-)

Comment: ... but of course, it can't work if you want to input a text file generated with the `tree` command.

Answer (score 2):

just came across this topic in my latex document too. The solution from @Daniel just worked partially. I had to add two more lines for replacing `tree`isch output.

```
\lstdefinestyle{tree}{
literate=
    {├}{{\smash{\raisebox{-1ex}{\rule{1pt}{\baselineskip}}}\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{1ex}{1pt}}}}1 
    {│}{{\smash{\raisebox{-1ex}{\rule{1pt}{\baselineskip}}}\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{1ex}{0pt}}}}1
    { }{~}1
    {─}{{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{1.5ex}{1pt}}}}1 
    {└}{{\smash{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{1pt}{\dimexpr\baselineskip-1.5ex}}}\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{1ex}{1pt}}}}1
}
```

The vertical line and the "space" was missing which gave me an error during compiling. I hope that this answer will help people who are not familiar with LaTeX. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on Overleaf, the previous examples left some missing characters.

```
\lstdefinestyle{tree}{
literate=
    {├}{{\smash{\raisebox{-1ex}{\rule{1pt}{\baselineskip}}}\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{1ex}{1pt}}}}1 
    {└}{{\smash{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{1pt}{\dimexpr\baselineskip-1.5ex}}}\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{1ex}{1pt}}}}1 
    {─}{{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{1.5ex}{1pt}}}}1 
    {│}{{\smash{\raisebox{-1ex}{\rule{1pt}{\baselineskip}}}\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{1ex}{0pt}}}}1 
}
```

The order of the lines matter.