# Print box drawing characters with pdfLaTeX

Tags: xetex, pdftex, unicode

I need to print some unicode characters (of box drawing family) in my document. I found this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208941/print-box-drawing-characters-from-shell-in-lstlisting) that is very similar to mine but is valid only for XeLaTeX. There is a valid way to do this with pdfLaTeX or I have to use XeLaTeX instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the symbols, if available on the keyboard, or the macros.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{└}{\textSFii}
\newunicodechar{├}{\textSFviii}
\newunicodechar{─}{\textSFx}
\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
├── Maildir/
└── scripts/
    ├── backup.sh*
    └── OLD/
        ├── backup_cleanup.sh.old
        └── backup.sh.old*
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's ok with verbatim environment but i still have the same problem with lstlisting environment.

Comment: Thank you, this works great. But can you explain why we need to type the `\newunicodechar` definitions? Why doesn't `pmboxdraw` define those characters in the first place?

Comment: The `utf8` encoding doesn't know such characters. The reason why you have to define the character and its command

Comment: @Tobia The stuff with `\newunicodechar` is not needed. Package `pmboxdraw` already handles it automatically, see my answer.

Answer (score 10):

This is an extension to Herbert's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281372/16967) and an answer to Tobia's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281368/print-box-drawing-characters-with-pdflatex#comment874485_281372).

Package `inputenc` with encoding option `utf8` allows the use of UTF-8 in TeX input files with 8-bit TeX engines. As prerequisite, the Unicode characters
must be known, how they are mapped to TeX code. The UTF-8 support of `inputenc` couples this with the font encoding. Therefore package `pmboxdraw` defines an artificial font encoding `pmboxdraw` and the related mapping file `pmboxdrawenc.dfu`, which is then automatically loaded. This simplifies Herbert's  example to:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
├── Maildir/
└── scripts/
    ├── backup.sh*
    └── OLD/
        ├── backup_cleanup.sh.old
        └── backup.sh.old*
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Compiled with:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016)
```

Version list of `\listfiles`:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
pmboxdraw.sty    2011/03/24 v1.1 Poor man's box drawing characters (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pmboxdrawenc.dfu    2011/03/24 v1.1 UTF-8 support for box drawing characters
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
  t1cmtt.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
 ***********
```

## LuaTeX/XeTeX version

LuaTeX and XeTeX support Unicode characters and package `inputenc` is deprecated. However, `pmboxdrawenc.dfu` can still be used to make the supported
characters active and expand to the symbols:

```
% arara: xelatex
% or
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}

\begingroup
  \def\DeclareUnicodeCharacter#1{%
    \begingroup
      \lccode`\~="#1\relax
    \lowercase{\endgroup
      \global\catcode`~=\active
      \gdef~%
    }%
  }%
  \input{pmboxdrawenc.dfu}%
\endgroup

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
├── Maildir/
└── scripts/
    ├── backup.sh*
    └── OLD/
        ├── backup_cleanup.sh.old
        └── backup.sh.old*
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nope. Using the system that comes in with `apt-get install texlive-xetex texlive-fonts-recommended lmodern` on Linux Mint 18 (Ubuntu 16.04) which seems to be version 2015.20160320-1, your example comes out without the line characters. I have to explicitly define the characters with `\newunicodechar`. Maybe I'm missing some other package? Or is my TeX Live too old?

Comment: @Tobia The question was to do it for *pdfTeX*, not XeTeX. I have updated the answer and added a version for LuaTeX/XeTeX.

Comment: I got an error because I mistakenly had the option `[utf8x]` for the package `inputenc`. Once I corrected that to `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, it all worked fine. . . BTW, not sure what `\listfiles` is supposed to do? I did not need that. (Pdf-LaTeX.)

Comment: @Henke `\listfiles` produces the version list shown in the answer.

Comment: Yeah, OK. That makes sense. I've never bothered about these logs and output files before. In my [scratch of your example](http://www.overleaf.com/project/5f819654b4c0360001b60687) I had to poke around a bit to find it -- button `Logs and output files` next to `Recompile`, and then `Other logs & files > log file` in the upper right. The version at overleaf seems to be relatively recent: `pmboxdraw.sty  2019/12/05 v1.4 Poor man's box drawing characters (HO)`. BTW, your answer (without `newunicodechar`) is better than the accepted one, and deserves to be upvoted. :-)