# Latex verbatim text 'as is' shows up as '???'

Tags: verbatim

I have got some special characters I wish Latex to treat 'as is', which I understood Verbatim is for (I'm new to Latex).

```
\begin{verbatim}
        ┌─┐
q_0: |0>┤M├
        └╥┘
 c_0: 0 ═╩═
\end{verbatim}
```

However the PDF result shows up as `???`

```
        ???
q_0: |0>?M?
        ???
 c_0: 0 ???
```

How can I show/print my special characters properly?

Comment: see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281368/print-box-drawing-characters-with-pdflatex

Comment: you have tagged the question as ascii but the issue you have is just because ═╩  is _not_ ascii

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One possibility is with the pmboxdraw package:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}
\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
        ┌─┐
q_0: |0>┤M├
        └╥┘
 c_0: 0 ═╩═
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another with lualatex and a suitable typewriter font:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{DejaVuSansMono}
\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
        ┌─┐
q_0: |0>┤M├
        └╥┘
 c_0: 0 ═╩═
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The first solution works great, though only when i put it in a new empty latex document. not my current one, trying to figure out  why its not doing anything (compiles just fine)

Comment: Can't seem to get it working in my current document, would you have a clue why?

Comment: minimize your document until you find the conflicting package.

Comment: Even when i remove everything in the document, and copy exactly your answer.. it still doesnt work. Even though it does when I make a new document. I tried restarting Texteditor.

Comment: Are you sure that your document is utf8 encoded?

Comment: I already had the following line \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} which didnt work. but when i went to edit > encoding > change to (utf8) which was alreayd at the top on position 1, it was fixed. Thanks a lot! working great now